# Convert Appointment to Email and send

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to convert an incoming appointment message to email and send.

```vb
Public Sub ConvertMeetingToEmail(ActiveFolder, Inbox As String)
        
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim Subfolder As Outlook.Folder

    Dim Item As Object
    Dim myMtg As Outlook.MeetingItem
    
    Dim objMsg As MailItem
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
      
    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNamespace.Folders(ActiveFolder)
    Set Folders = myFolder.Folders
    Set Subfolder = Folders.Item(Inbox)
    
    For Each Item In Subfolder.Items
        
        If Item.MessageClass = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request" Then
            'Convert Appointment to Email and Forward message
            'Its Sudo-code and not working
            objMsg.To = "example@emp.com"
            objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject
            objMsg.Body = Item.Body
            objMsg.Send
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

It is important to copy body text from Appointment as well as Subject and send to another email address.

I cannot forward this appointment. I have to convert it to email.

**UPDATE**

I added one line of code and it works:

```
Set myMtg = Item

objMsg.To = "example@emp.com"
objMsg.Subject = myMtg.Subject
objMsg.Body = myMtg.Body
objMsg.Send
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an existing meeting item as a regular email you need to set the [MessageClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/meetingitem-messageclass-property-outlook) property to `IPM.Note`first. The `MessageClass` property links the item to the form on which it is based. When an item is selected, Outlook uses the message class to locate the form and expose its properties, such as `Reply` commands. Then you can cast the object to the `MailItem` class and call the Send method (of course, after specifying recipients).

At the opposite side, the [Forward](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/meetingitem-forward-method-outlook) method of the `MeetingItem` class executes the `Forward` action for an item and returns the resulting copy as a MeetingItem object. So, basically a new `MeetingItem` object that represents the new meeting item is returned which can be sent.

Comment: As I said Iam new in VBA and in Programming generally. Could you pleace give an example based on my code above?

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to forward a meeting item or send a report represented by the mail item?

Comment: Ill forward a meeting but not as meeting item. Let's say meeting email has date, time, recipients etc. - I will get all this metadata and forward it to another email adress as plane email with this data as email body

Comment: Call `Forward`, then on the returned item set the `MessageClass` property to `IPM.Note` and cast it to a mail item object. Viola, you are free to call `Send` now.